# Update Module List odoo

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8

How Can i update module list From terminal in

openerp and odoo(v8) ?

Is there any way to achieve this from terminal?

I want to update module list Without Using Webclient

Answer (score 1):

You can update all module list from the terminal using:

```
./openerp-server -u all -d dbname --addons-path=addons/
```

Comment: its not working when you are giving external path for addons

Answer (score 1):

You can create xml-file that calls ir.module.module objects update_list function. Like this:

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <function model="ir.module.module" name="update_list"/>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Now if you add this xml-file to module data (like you would add any other view definition or other xml-files) that ***update_list*** function gets called every time you update this module.

For example you added this to a new module named **"your_custom_module_updater"**,  so now you can start odoo with:

```
./odoo.py -u your_custom_module_updater
```

and that module list should update every time from now on.

> *note: you still need to manually update the list for your_custom_module_updater to install it :)

**Update**: By manipulating with ir_module_module table you can add, install, uninstall or upgrade the module

-->Module list will be updated automatically when you upgrade your module.

Comment: I am unable to update Module list Manually Bcz i am unable to login into DB without Updating Module list

Comment: Why is that ? Do you get some kind of error ? Can you explain ?

Comment: File "/home/swapnesh/WorkSpace/latest_odoo/openerp/service/server.py", line 929, in preload_registries
    registry = RegistryManager.new(dbname, update_module=update_module)
  File "/home/swapnesh/WorkSpace/latest_odoo/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 370, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/home/swapnesh/WorkSpace/latest_odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 326, in load_modules
    modobj.button_upgrade(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, ids)

Comment: File "/home/swapnesh/WorkSpace/latest_odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/swapnesh/WorkSpace/latest_odoo/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 559, in button_upgrade
    raise orm.except_orm(_('Error'), _('You try to upgrade a module that depends on the module: %s.\nBut this module is not available in your system.') % (dep.name,))

Comment: Check your module's   __openerp__.py   file . In that -->'depends' ... check that all the dependent modules are present in your -->>addons folder or not. If any of them is not present then you might get this error.

Comment: ya it was not before but now it is in same

Comment: So what is the status ? Has the issue been solved or not ? Do you still get the error ?

Comment: i manually added record of that particular module in 'ir_module_module;' to this overcome issue

Comment: I have updated my answer above. You can mark the answer correct if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like 
[Command line interface](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/cmdline.html)

```
python openerp.py or odoo.py --db-filter=db_name -d db_name -u module list
```

Comment: using -u i am unable to get updated module list
actually i want to update module list and that after want to install it using -i module_name

Comment: i have tried using -u all but still i am unable to get my module in list

Comment: can u provide me ur module __init__.py and __openerp__.py file put ur code  http://notepad.cc/sofiba43

Answer (score -1):

In odoo V9
Activate developer mode. Click on your username in upper right corner > About > Activate Developer mode
Update modules/apps list
Main menu > Apps > Update apps list